# get dataset from parent

Tags: javascript, html

I have the `element` inside this structure:

```
<div data-unit="5" data-id="0" id="unit-0" class="session-unit-container unit-columns">
  <h1 class="unit-title">5</h1>
  <div class="session-unit">
    <div id="element" class="session-card" draggable="false" style="">Item 5</div> // here is the element
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I get the `data-unit="5"` of the parent element when I select the `element`?

Comment: how do you mean `select the element`? Give it focus by starting the drag?

Comment: Do you have more than one container, or more than one element with a session-card class?

Comment: `const element = document.getElementById('element')`

Comment: I may have more than one element inside `session-unit` and one single `session-unit` inside each `session-unit-container`

Comment: `element.parentNode.parentNode.dataset.unit`?

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand what you mean by saying `when I select the element`. You mean when you click? When you `mouse select` the text?

Anyway, the way to access the value is the following:

```js
// Here I select the element I am interested for.
let element = document.getElementById('element');

// Here I just console.log the value of the data-unit
console.log(`Here Is The data-unit Value: ${element.parentNode.parentNode.dataset.unit}`);
```

```html
<div data-unit="5" data-id="0" id="unit-0" class="session-unit-container unit-columns">
  <h1 class="unit-title">5</h1>
  <div class="session-unit">
    <div id="element" class="session-card" draggable="false" style="">Item 5</div> // here is the element
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have more than one container containing cards you can attach a listener to each container and, if the element you clicked on was a card, log the value of the data attribute.

(Note: if you do have multiple containers of cards don't give each card the same id.)

```js
// Cache the container elements
const containers = document.querySelectorAll('.session-unit-container');

// Add listeners to them
containers.forEach(container => {
  container.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);
});

function handleClick(e) {

  // Get the class list from the element that was clicked
  const { classList } = e.target;

  // If it's a card...
  if (classList.contains('session-card')) {

    // Locate the container element
    const parent = e.target.closest('.session-unit-container');

    // And get its unit value from the dataset
    const { unit } = parent.dataset;

    console.log(unit);

  }

}
```

```css
.session-card:hover { cursor: pointer; color: red; }
```

```html
<div data-unit="2" data-id="0" id="unit-0" class="session-unit-container unit-columns">
  <h3 class="unit-title">2</h3>
  <div class="session-unit">
    <div class="session-card" draggable="false" style="">Item 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div data-unit="5" data-id="0" id="unit-0" class="session-unit-container unit-columns">
  <h3 class="unit-title">5</h3>
  <div class="session-unit">
    <div class="session-card" draggable="false" style="">Item 5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Additional documentation

- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
- [`closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)
- [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)
- [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)